# How to construct the English alphabet using a loop in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I construct the English alphabet using a for loop, i.e. without writing all the characters manually?

I normally do:

```
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

But I think there must be a more elegant way to achieve this. This can be easily done in `C` as `char`s are merely ASCII codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
        printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

But since Swift supports Unicode, it is a little tricky. We can construct a `ClosedRange<String>` as in `let alphabet = "a"..."z"` which is helpful in comparing whether a character is between "a" and "z", but I couldn't find an easy way to extract all possible values in a closed range.

Comment: One way could be  `for char in 97...122 { print(Character(Unicode.Scalar(char)!)) }`

Comment: Thanks! Please submit this as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ascii values in the loop and then create characters from the value using Unicode.Scalar

```
for char in 97...122 {    
    print(Character(Unicode.Scalar(char)!))
}
```

A longer version of the for loop header is

```
for char in Unicode.Scalar("a").value...Unicode.Scalar("z").value {
```